# RSS feed url returning empty

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, rss, feed

I'm trying to render an rss feed from an external xml file in a Wordpress .php page:

```
    <?php
    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=uk');
    $feed = array();

    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {

        $item = array (
            'guid' => $node->getElementsByTagName('guid')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
           );

        array_push($feed, $item);
    }
    $limit = 3;
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
        $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
        $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
        echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
        echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
        echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
    }
   ?>
```

Thanks to Bavotasan's article called "An Easy Way to Display an RSS Feed with PHP", this works PERFECTLY with the BBC url shown. BUT when I change the BBC url to an external (public) url that CAN be viewed in a browser with no errors, it doesn't work. Even a var_dump of $rss immediately before the "foreach" statement returns this:

```
    object(DOMDocument)#51 (34) { ["doctype"]=> NULL ["implementation"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["documentElement"]=> NULL ["actualEncoding"]=> NULL ["encoding"]=> NULL ["xmlEncoding"]=> NULL ["standalone"]=> bool(true) ["xmlStandalone"]=> bool(true) ["version"]=> string(3) "1.0" ["xmlVersion"]=> string(3) "1.0" ["strictErrorChecking"]=> bool(true) ["documentURI"]=> NULL ["config"]=> NULL ["formatOutput"]=> bool(false) ["validateOnParse"]=> bool(false) ["resolveExternals"]=> bool(false) ["preserveWhiteSpace"]=> bool(true) ["recover"]=> bool(false) ["substituteEntities"]=> bool(false) ["nodeName"]=> string(9) "#document" ["nodeValue"]=> NULL ["nodeType"]=> int(9) ["parentNode"]=> NULL ["childNodes"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["firstChild"]=> NULL ["lastChild"]=> NULL ["previousSibling"]=> NULL ["attributes"]=> NULL ["ownerDocument"]=> NULL ["namespaceURI"]=> NULL ["prefix"]=> string(0) "" ["localName"]=> NULL ["baseURI"]=> NULL ["textContent"]=> string(0) "" }
```

To be massively unhelpful I'm not at liberty to refer to the offending url, but am hoping there can only be a handful of instances where a valid url that renders fine in a browser cannot be assigned to a variable using this method.

opening lines of bbc source code: (working):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet title="XSL_formatting" type="text/xsl" href="/shared/bsp/xsl/rss/nolsol.xsl"?>

    <rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
```

opening lines of desired source code (NOT working):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:tp="http://www.xxxxxxxx.co.uk/rss/">
```

The respective XML structures are almost identical and share a common:

```
    <channel><title>
    <channel><link>
    <channel><description>
```

...etc. My question is why won't the offending url work? Thanks in advance...

NB I'm at a fairly infant level of php / xml knowledge, so laymen's terms and lego-brick simple explanations are appreciated.

*update*

Success at last - colleague tried to see if feed url was zipped - and it was. So updated code is:

```
    function download_page($path){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
    $retValue = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $retValue;
}

$foo = download_page('http://xxxxxxxx.xml');
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->loadXML($foo);

$feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {

    $item = array (
        'guid' => $node->getElementsByTagName('guid')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
       );

    array_push($feed, $item);
}
$limit = 3;
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
    echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
    echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
}
```

Thanks for all help...

Comment: Could you expand on "it doesn't work" a little, please? And is there any way you could take the document that you can't reveal, and produce a censored version that (a) you can show us, and (b) still triggers whatever problem you're seeing -- even if it just has a single fake article in it?

Comment: (Also, does the offending feed validate at http://feedvalidator.org ? That might quickly tell you whether the feed is somehow faulty, or otherwise give some clues.)

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your prompt response, the feed validated successfully at feedvalidator with some recommendations... I will try and get a remote file suitably anon-ified and hosted somewhere shortly...

Comment: I think I'm a little closer: I viewed the source of the problematic rss xml file and saved it as a new .xml file, then put it on a different hosting server - and it worked fine! Does this suggest my problem is some kind of config/permissions issue with where the original .xml file is hosted? Or with some parameters I should be using in the 'load'? Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not sure. It could be some kind of encoding issue (which copying/pasting/saving the file could be fixing without you necessarily noticing), or a permissions problem, or even that the feed server is checking request headers in some particular way. It's very hard to debug this without having the actual feed URL. What do you see if you just do: `$feed_source = file_get_contents('http://that.feed.url/...'); echo $feed_source;`? You *should* see the feed content, but I'm wondering if it'll actually show you an error that might help figure out what's going on.

Comment: Ah. Someone cleverer than I suggested it was a zipped feed and the browser was unzipping it - he was right! I had no idea... He got around it with a new function using a curl_init() and download_page instead. Will try and post code in a sec...thanks for help to date :-)